# How to append a dictionary after entering an empty string

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

My code has to ask for a name and age everytime, and when an empty sting is entered the entered name and age is put into a dictionary.

All I have is this:

```
askMore = True
dictionary = {}
while askMore:
    name = input("Name or an empty string to stop: ")
    age = int(input ("Age: "))
    if not name:
        print(dictionary)
        askMore = False
    else:
        dictionary[name] = age
        print(dictionary)
```

Like it works but not the way it suppose to. It prints the answer after I enter the age like so:

```
Name or an empty string to stop: asdg
Age: 1
{'asdg': 1}
Name or an empty string to stop: blaah
Age: 12
{'asdg': 1, 'blaah': 12}
```

And then continues to ask

```
Enter a name or an empty string to stop:
```

But when I enter an empty string it prints out the "Enter a name or an empty string to stop:" and then "Age:" and then an error.

I want it to print out the whole dictionary of entered names and ages after I enter an empty string, like so:

```
{'asdg': 1, 'blaah': 12}
```

Not everytime I add a name or age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think carefully about the order that you want to do things here:

1. Ask for a name
2. If the user entered a name ask for an age
3. Insert the name and age into the dictionary
4. Repeat steps 1 through 3 until the user doesn't enter a name

This is my first rough draft of how to do this. However, this isn't clear enough to directly translate it into code, so we need to refine our verbal description. The important part is that we need to check the name before even trying to ask for the age. So let's try to do it like this:

1. Ask for a name
2. While the name is not blank

   a. Ask for an age

   b. Insert the name and age into the dictionary

   c. Ask for a name
3. Print the dictionary

While writing this, I kept in mind how a while loop works and that I need to check the condition in the while loop immediately after asking the user for a name. Also, we print the dictionary after the loop finishes instead of each time the loop iterates.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your logic: you insist on reading both values and converting `age` to int before you check whether it's time to stop.  Fix the logic order.

```
name = input("Name or an empty string to stop: ")

while name:

    age = int(input ("Age: "))
    dictionary[name] = age
    print(dictionary)
    name = input("Name or an empty string to stop: ")

print(dictionary)
```